# Load Reactjs Bootstrap styling

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm very new to reactjs. There is a third-party library called [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) that I want to use in my project. I installed it via yarn and when I want to use it's components, nothing happens! For example:

```
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
<Button variant="success">Sign In</Button>
```

has no effect on a button. In elements I can see that the class assigned:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Sign In</button>
```

but there isn't any effect in button!! What should I do?
If you need any clarification, simply ask for it. Thank you!

Comment: Have you added `bootstrap.css`?

Comment: Do I have to? Nothing mentioned in documentation for this...

Comment: reactstrap contains ready-to-use components, you need to add bootstrap CSS to handle those components style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `bootstrap.css`, either by adding link in `index.html`

```
<link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
```

or by importing in `index.js` file after installing `bootstrap` using `yarn` / `npm`.

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-vxsuu?fontsize=14)

Comment: Thank you, this works. Can you tell me if I don't want to use a CDN for this job and install bootstrap via yarn, how can I use it?

Comment: You can import bootstrap.css in index.js file as `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` after installing bootstrap using yarn.